# Value of input returning blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, modal-dialog

I am trying to retrieve the value of an input in my code behind, but it is returning `""`. I am using the remodal plugin to display a popup, and then I have a textbox within this modal popup

Here is the ASP.NET code I am using.

```
<a href="#addCustomer" class="addButton">Add Customer</a>    

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="addCustomer">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h1>Add Customer</h1>
    <h4>Customer</h4>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="sr-only" for="name2">Customer</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TXT_CreateCustomer" placeholder="Customer" name="name2" runat="server"/>
        <i class="fa fa-building-o form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
  <br />
  <button id="BTN_NewJob_AddCustomer" data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm" runat="server" onserverclick="BTN_NewJob_AddCustomer_ServerClick">Create Customer</button>
</div>
```

This is the C# server code that I am using to try and retrieve that value from the textbox.

```
protected void BTN_NewJob_AddCustomer_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string example = TXT_CreateCustomer.Value;
}
```

The server code is very simple and should work, but it only returns `""` when text is typed into the textbox.

Any ideas on what would prevent getting the text from the textbox?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the IsPostback on page_load?

Comment: Yes, it is posting back, and the event handler is firing correctly.

Comment: Probably I have not explained well my question. What do you do in the Page_Load event? Are you setting the TextBox to an empty string whithout checking if this is a Page_Load called by a Postback?

Comment: I am not doing anything in the Pagae_Load event. I did put an if(IsPostBack) to make sure it is posting back properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the asp: on your form elements, therefore they are not filling in. asp:input instead of input, also runat='server' is required.

Edit: Sorry, let me clarify. Not asp:input, asp:textbox.

So, for example:

```
<asp:Textbox id="myTextBox" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I am using the `runat="server"` tag. But why would I need to use `asp:`? Should I not be able to use HTML in the ASP page as well?

Comment: I prefer to use the `<input>` tag, but I thought of this earlier, and even the `<asp:TextBox>` tag does not return a value in the code behind.

Comment: You can use HTML elements but there's no linkage to the ASP engine if you do that. The asp: equivilents such as textbox are wrappers, and provide that mechanism. I also do not see runat="server" in your input tag, so I'm not sure what you're saying :) Edit: sorry nevermind I see it.. Still needs to be asp:Textbox, try it and let me know!

Comment: Hmmm. I have used them before and they work with the code behind as long as the `runat="server"` property is present.

Look at the end of the input tag and the runat=server is there.

Comment: I'll give it a try with the asp:TextBox

Comment: Just tried it out with the asp:TextBox and same result. Returns `""`

Comment: Something else I noticed, try .Text instead of .value. The Microsoft documentation has this:

Comment: .Value is used for the HTML tag. When using the asp:TextBox .Text is needed.

Comment: Are other elements in the form working correctly? I wonder if you can trace it with F12 to see the HTTP posts to make sure it's actually posting back the values?

Comment: Hmm this is the first element I have tried to retrieve the value from. I will try another that is not inside the modal.

Comment: Other elements that are not inside the modal popup return their values properly. They are `<input>` as well.

Comment: Is the modal popup actually using an AJAX? Do you need scriptmanager? - I remember using a framework (called GreyBox) that you can add an option to do a reload after it closes, but everything was Javascript/jQuery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95622/discussion-between-chase-ernst-and-dan-chase).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, will it help or no, but try to use following in the code behind:

```
string example = TXT_CreateCustomer.innerText;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no `.innerText` attribute for the <input>

Comment: @ChaseErnst oh sorry, my mistake. Try to use TXT_CreateCustomer.Value, it should work fine

Comment: That is what I am using in the example. From what I can tell in my research, it is because the modal dialog is being taken out of the form when it is created.